# Is it possible to auto break a table with contents that are too long at the same row? I tried both tabularx and longtable

Tags: longtable, tabularx

I have a table with 2 columns. The 2nd column has a content which exceeds a page limit. I wish latex can break it automatically at the end of the page and continue on the next. here's my example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| p{.75\textwidth} | p{.20\textwidth} |} 
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr \\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! No, a long table can be broken only at a new row.

Comment: Yes, it is possible (in principle), but no, I do not know how.  It is not a standard feature provided by any of the tabular-like environments.

Comment: You should better use a list perhaps alongs with a tcolorbox (and probably less lines).

Comment: @JPi I think so too but I've been searching the whole day and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If there's no other alternatives I guess tcolorbox should be acceptable too...

Comment: almost all examples of two column tables with one short and one long entry are better set as a list, then page breaking mid-item is automatic

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm new to Latex, can you show me an example of how it could be done or give me a link with explanations or examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always such "tables" are best set as a list. Here I show the basic default `description` formatting but list formatting is highly flexible, perhaps most easily by use of the `enumitem` package.  Note that unlike table rows list items always break over a page (here I show breaking over a column in two-column mode, just to make a smaller example).

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\hyphenation{ss-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-ss 
             ss-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-sr
             ss-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-ss
             ss-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-ss
             ss-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-ss
             }

\addtolength\textheight{-10\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[foo]bar  
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo]bar 
\item[foo] bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss
  sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss
  sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss
  ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss
  ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss
  sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss
  ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss
  ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss
  sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss
  ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss
  ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss
  sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss
  ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss
  ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr
\item[foo] bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss
  sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss
  sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss
  ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss
  ssssssssssss ssssss
\item[foo] bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss
  sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss
  sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss
  ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
  sssssssssssssssr bassssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss
  ssssssssssss ssssss zzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzz
\end{description}

\end{document}
```